# twisted transport.write in a non-reactor thread

Tags: python, twisted, pyqt4, reactor

I am designing a gui application as a client for a server where i have 3 classes

a class for twisted protocol , another for the factory and the third for the pyqt thread it self. how can i send data from the pyqt thread , as example if a button was clicked how can i send a command using the current twisted connection, here is a copy of my codes

```
from OpenSSL import SSL;import sys
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.internet import ssl, protocol
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from gui import Ui_clientgui

class clientgui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_clientgui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        try:reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)
        except:pass

class Client(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        global server_options
        server_options['connection'] = True

    def send(self,data):
        self.transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        server_options['connection'] = False

    def dataReceived(self, line):
        print "receive:", line

class ClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = Client
    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection failed'
        try:reactor.stop()
        except:pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    import qt4reactor
    qt4reactor.install()
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    factory = ClientFactory()
    reactor.connectSSL('localhost', 8080, factory, ssl.ClientContextFactory())
    application = clientgui(reactor)
    application.show()
    reactor.runReturn()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [qt4reactor](https://launchpad.net/qt4reactor), you don't need to mess around with multiple threads at all; Twisted will run in the QT thread and they can freely touch each others' data structures.

If you want to do this with threads though, your example already contains the solution: `reactor.callFromThread`.  (I would recommend doing `callFromThread(client.send)` rather than `callFromThread(transport.write)` because the `Client` is a `Protocol` and therefore lives in Twisted's universe more than in Qt's.